# jQuery AutoComplete (jQuery UI 1.8rc3) with ASP.NET web service

Tags: asp.net, web-services, jquery-ui, autocomplete

Currently, I have this version of the autocomplete control working when returning XML from a .ashx handler. The xml looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no" ?> 
<States>
<State>
  <Code>CA</Code> 
  <Name>California</Name> 
</State>
<State>
  <Code>NC</Code> 
  <Name>North Carolina</Name> 
</State>
<State>
  <Code>SC</Code> 
  <Name>South Carolina</Name> 
</State>
```

The autocomplete code looks like this:

```
    $('.autocompleteTest').autocomplete(
    {
        source: function(request, response) {
            var list = [];
            $.ajax({
                url: "http://commonservices.qa.kirkland.com/StateLookup.ashx",
                dataType: "xml",
                async: false,
                data: request,
                success: function(xmlResponse) {
                    list = $("State", xmlResponse).map(function() {
                        return {
                            value: $("Code", this).text(),
                            label: $("Name", this).text()
                        };
                    }).get();
                }
            });
            response(list);
        },
        focus: function(event, ui) {
            $('.autocompleteTest').val(ui.item.label);
            return false;
        },
        select: function(event, ui) {
            $('.autocompleteTest').val(ui.item.label);
            $('.autocompleteValue').val(ui.item.value);
            return false;
        }

    });
```

For various reasons, I'd rather be calling an ASP.NET web service, but I can't get it to work. To change over to the service (I'm doing a local service to keep it simple), the start of the autocomplete code is:

```
    $('.autocompleteTest').autocomplete(
    {
        source: function(request, response) {
            var list = [];
            $.ajax({
                url: "/Services/GeneralLookup.asmx/StateList",
                dataType: "xml",
```

This code is on a page at the root of the site and the GeneralLookup.asmx is in a subfolder named Services. But a breakpoint in the web service never gets hit, and no autocomplete list is generated. In case it makes a difference, the XML that comes from the asmx is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
<string xmlns="http://www.kirkland.com/"><State> <Code>CA</Code> <Name>California</Name> </State> <State> <Code>NC</Code> <Name>North Carolina</Name> </State> <State> <Code>SC</Code> <Name>South Carolina</Name> </State></string>
```

Functionally equivalent since I never use the name of the root node in the mapping code. I haven't seen anything in the jQuery docs about calling a .asmx service from this control, but a .ajax call is a .ajax call, right?

I've tried various different paths to the .asmx (~/Services/), and I've even moved the service to be in the same path to eliminate these issues. No luck with either.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I got the autocomplete to work with .asmx by using JSON.  Here is an example of what I did:

JavaScript:

```
$("#tbNameFilter").autocomplete({
    source: function (request, response) {
        $.ajax({
            url: "/Services/AutocompleteService.asmx/Aoi_Autocomplete",
            data: "{ 'q': '" + request.term + "', 'limit': '10' }",
            dataType: "json",
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataFilter: function (data) { return data; },
            success: function (data) {
                response($.map(data.d, function (item) {
                    return {
                        label: item.Name,
                        value: item.Name
                    }
                }))
            }
        });
    },
    minLength: 1
});
```

Web Service:

```
[WebMethod]
public List<FAD_Aoi> Aoi_Autocomplete(String q, int limit)
```

Comment: This is perfect. Solved my problem exactly.